# GPS antenna not working

Tags: rf, antenna, gnss, lna, patch-antenna

We are developing a GPS+LTE project based on the LE910S1-EAG module. We use a GPS LNA NJG1159PHH and an ACAG0301-1575 GPS antenna.

[image: LE910S1-EAG]

In this module GNSS_LNA_EN is left open and GNSS_ANT_RF_OUT is connected to pin R9 if the GPS LNA.

[image: GPS LNA]

[NJG1159PHH](https://www.nisshinbo-microdevices.co.jp/en/products/front-end-module/spec/?product=njg1159phh) is powered by 1.8 V and VCTL is also connected to 1.8 V.

[image: gps antenna]

The antenna is connected to ground and L2, L4 junction. The antenna matching circuit is obtained from the [ACAG0301-1575 datasheet](https://abracon.com/datasheets/ACAG0301-1575-T.pdf). The antenna has two metal pads and has three connections in the datasheet. The ground here also is connected to the power supply ground.

[image: antena pcb connections]

When we powered up the module we are able to see the NMEA output from the UART and it doesn't contain any valid GNSS or other values:

```
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56
$GNGLL,,,,,,V,N*7A
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,1*33
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,4*36
$GPGSV,1,1,00,0*65
$GBGSV,1,1,00,0*77
$GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,V*37
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56
$GNGLL,,,,,,V,N*7A
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,1*33
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99,4*36
$GPGSV,1,1,00,0*65
$GBGSV,1,1,00,0*77
$GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,V*37
```

Comment: Have you checked your GPS repeater? Are you sure you've got a good GPS signal for it to recieve?

Comment: @Puffafish no, we have no gps repeater, we just took outside for testing

Comment: Does it work if you use an external antenna connected to J3?

Comment: @liorbilia, yes it worked when we used a lna+antenna module connected to J3 and powered with a 1v8. i think gnss signals are weak to dectect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rotating the antenna 180 degrees? I think the feed line is in the bottom left, and that's where the marking is on the antenna. I'm just designing a board with this antenna now, so I'll be able to test in a couple of weeks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/352594)